# Using resample on dataframe containing multiple Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

say I have a dataframe containing multiple time series like here:

```
Time Stamp          Name        Load    
03/01/2017 00:00:00 CAPITL      1040.80 
03/01/2017 00:00:00 EST CENTRL  1468.30 
03/01/2017 00:00:00 EST DUNWOD  516.90  
03/01/2017 00:05:00 CAPITL      1542.80 
03/01/2017 00:05:00 EST CENTRL  568.30  
03/01/2017 00:05:00 EST DUNWOD  1542.90
```

and I want to use DataFrame.resample("60min").mean() to get less resolution on the time series data, but still have the second column to identify the separate time series by names. Could anybody help me out?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first groupby Name and then resample:

```
df.groupby('Name').resample('60T', on='Time Stamp').mean()
```